# TinyMCE in Angular errors with cant access body and $sce

Tags: angularjs, tinymce

I'm trying to get Tiny MCE to work in angular and having less than stellar success with it.

Currently I cant get past this error:

> Unable to get property 'body' of undefined or null reference

I even tried to just get a basic fiddle running with it but failed at that too. http://jsfiddle.net/m0z0n6dL/

As far as I understand all you need is the tinymce-angular script and then decorate your textbox with `<textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="text" type="text"><textarea>`

and to include it in the module

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.tinymce']);
```

But this is failing on:

> Unknown provider $sceProvider <- $sce <- uiTinymceDirective

If anyone could show me a simple example using CDNs for angular and tinymce dependencies I would be really happy.

Comment: JensB, did my answer works?

Comment: @developer033 The TinyMCE angular plugin seems to be to much hassle for the result so I went with this instead https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular. For simple text styling it is plenty.

Comment: @developer033 Also, TinyMCE-Angular seems to not like being inside ng-repeats and having to deal with ng-show and ng-if's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems you **MUST** instantiate your module as `ui.tinymce`, otherwise it doesn't work.

Here's an *example*:

```js
angular.module('ui.tinymce')
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.updateHtml = function() {
      $scope.tinymceHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(ctrl.tinymce);
    };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ui.tinymce">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.3.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/master/src/tinymce.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form method="post">
    <textarea ui-tinymce
      ng-model="tinymce"
      ng-change="updateHtml()"></textarea>
  </form>
  <div ng-bind-html="tinymceHtml"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** The example above won't compile well because the **stacksnippets** is blocking the *url* of `tinymce`.

You can see the full demo [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/girRFcGDoMcpvwDuurcG?p=preview) without errors.

Comment: Really annoying to have to name the module after TMCE, what if other modules make the same requirement.

Comment: Yes.. it's really bad, but did it work with my example right?